# Copying sections in hexl-mode

Tags: emacs, hex-editors

When using `hexl-mode` in emacs to view a binary file, is there any way of copying and pasting a section into another file?

I have tried it with the standard `C-Spc`, select a region, `M-w`

But pasting this into a new file treats the whole thing like normal text, i.e. I get a text file that looks like lots of these:

```
000159a0: 6e00 1295 00e0 3400 0a51 0942 0701 1295  n.....4..Q.B....
```

i.e. its making a literal copy of the text, not copying the binary data it is representing

What I want to do is copy a section, paste it into a new file such that I get a binary representation of that section

In other words I want to be able to generate new binary files from parts of an original binary file using hexl-mode for viewing the original binary file

Hope that makes sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a cool feature, but unforuntately `hexl-mode` doesn't do that. The next best thing you can do is clip the file with `head` and `tail`, for example to yank `file.txt` from 000002a0 to 00000340, you'd run

```
head file.txt -c $((0x00000340)) | tail -c +$((0x000002a0)) | xclip -sel c
```

Comment: very good, I also noted that you can search for a byte position in hexl-mode, then if you exit hexl-mode (back into Fundamental) the cursor will remain in that position, useful if you then want to copy from there to the end of the file as you can then cut and paste as desired

Comment: also thats the first i've ever heard of xclip - its brilliant! Strikes me that someone half competent in elisp could turn that shell snippet into a very handy emacs function, unfortunately I am << half competent..

Comment: As someone half competent in elisp, I've written a function called `hexl-copy-region` that does exactly what you want: http://pastebin.com/raw/D5b4kxZJ

It just goes in and out of `hexl-mode` to copy the text, like you mentioned in your first post.